# How to get gridFsFile content in spring data mongodb

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In spring-data-mongodb version 2.0.0 i can call a findOne method on [gridFsOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/api/) and i get a com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile back:

```
com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile gridFsFile = gridFsOperations.findOne(query(whereMetaData("firstName").is("Hardy")));
```

Now how can i get the content of this GridFSFile?

I understand that i can query for a filename and get a back GridFsResource. From this i can get the content as inputStream:

```
GridFsResource gridRes1 = gridFsOperations.getResource("myFile1.txt");
InputStream is = gridRes.getInputStream();
```

But this does not work for GridFSFile. And i also cannot get a resource by meta-data, but only by filename.

Comment: I added a improvement request in spring-data-mogodb that could help here: [DATAMONGO-1813](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1813)

Comment: I followed the recent changes version 2.1 M2 of spring data mongoDb. There it takes the GridFsFile, reads the location name and creates a GridFsResource. This however still doesn't solve the issue. In my mind, the implementation should use the unique id of the GridFsFile. However, I didn't find out how to tell this the developers.